# CLion IDE does not resolve header files when use remote host

Tags: clion

I use CLion IDE for a small TensorRT project. The project and related libraries (Cuda, TensorRT) are both located on a ssh server. One version of the project is cloned from the server and run locally. I managed to sync project between the server and local and build the project successfully (using command line `cmake` and `make`). One problem is CLion can not resolve header files (that are located remotely, for example `NvInfer.h` in TensorRT libraries), therefore code auto completion also does not work. I have tried flowing workarounds:

1. Include path to the header files to `CMakeLists.txt` by using `include_directories()`
2. `Tool` -> `Resync with remote hosts`.
3. Create `toolchain` and map remote host like in [CLion official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html).
4. I also referred to [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003286019-Autocompletion-not-available-when-using-remote-host) question and other similar questions but it still does not work.

If you have successfully setup CLion for remote development, please help me. Thank you for reading.

**More information:**

A few days ago. I found that the header files are silently installed in `.cache/JetBrains/CLion2020.3/.remote/MyHostName_PortNumber/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/the_header_files.h`. But now their aren't. How can i make CLion to install them again.

Comment: Are you editing the *local* repository, or are you really editing the *remote* repository? If you're editing the local repository, then you need to include all third-party library development packages on your local system (unless they are included as sub-modules of the repository, in which case you must make sure that you fetch them as well). If you use sub-modules with Git, it's well-documented how to fetch them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank your response. A few day ago. I found that the header files are silently installed in `.cache/JetBrains/CLion2020.3/.remote/MyHostName_PortNumber/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/the_header_files.h`. But now their aren't. How can i make CLion to install them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found the answer. The reason is CLion does not install header files to local because I am using a cmake version that is not supported by CLion. I uninstall cmake on the ssh server and reinstall it with CLion-supported version (3.17.1). Thank you!

Comment: Was it CMake 3.20 which is unsupported?

Comment: @MaximBanaev Yes, I installed Cmake 3.20 and it does not work with CLion newest version. 3.17 is the newest version of CMake that CLion supports now.

Comment: Funny, I thought it's 3.19 because they bundle it with IDE

Comment: @MaximBanaev Maybe it depends on version of CLion in your client. I use Clion ver 20.03.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem and I found that only part of the header files could not be parsed(unisth.h was found, but sys/stat.h did not).The real reason is that these files exist as symbolic links on my Ubuntu. During synchronization, Clion will first use `tar` to package the files, and then download them locally. By default, the symbolic links will not be parsed to the corresponding files.To solve this problem,I enable the **clion.remote.tar.dereference** key in the Registry(go to **Help | Find Action** or press Ctrl+Shift+A, type Registry, and search for the key by name),after that, click **Tools | Resync with Remote Hosts**.If it doesn't work, you may need delete your local cache manual(maybe in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2021.1.remote), and click **Tools | Resync with Remote Hosts**.