# CLion remote deployement cannot find system headers due to fail header directory downloading

Tags: c++, clion

I am using CLion 2022.3.2 and remote deployment to read code in Folly. Folly project relies on some external headers, e.g., `glog`, which are installed in the system folders by `dnf` command, e.g., `/usr/include`. I am using CMake (3.20.2) to build the project. CMake can successfully build the project and all executable targets work well. However, when I open some Folly cpp files that includes system headers, e.g., `#include <glog/logging.h>`, `#include <random>`, Clion complains "'glog/logging.h' files not find.".

I have try to find some solutions. The common advice is to run **Tools -> Resync with Remote Hosts**. When I run this command, Clion complains "Downloaded failed /usr/include", "Downloaded failed /usr/local/include", and etc. I cannot find extra debug messages to resolve the fail downloading. Thank you for give me some advice.

EDIT:
I look into the log of CLion, and find the following warning:

```
WARN - #c.i.e.p.OSProcessHandler - Process has been already terminated: /usr/bin/rsync -zar -v -e "ssh -p 22 " --log-file=/private/var/folders/8_/s7_qf53d5nb5szqvs136g7vm0000gp/T/rsync_download1.log --files-from=/private/var/folders/8_/s7_qf53d5nb5szqvs136g7vm0000gp/T/fileList1.txt myname@myip:/usr/local/lib/clang/15.0.7/include/ include
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802186/6778553.

> The real reason is that these files exist as symbolic links on my
> Ubuntu. During synchronization, Clion will first use tar to package
> the files, and then download them locally. By default, the symbolic
> links will not be parsed to the corresponding files.

I have fixed the problem by following the suggestion in the previous answer:
enable **clion.remote.tar.dereference** in Registry of CLion.